# Formatting of Table in JavaScript & Repeat table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I have a view in mySQL Workbench and I am getting this Data into a .js file like this:

```
$('#table_div').append('<table id="Overview" border="1" class="compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr><th>Customer</th><th>Program Name</th><th>Vehicle Model</th><th>CBU</th><th>PLM Step</th><</tr></tfoot></table>');
    var mytable = $('#Overview').dataTable({
        "ajax": {
        "url": "php/OPS_RFQ_global_php.php",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": {
                    "Filtera": Filtera,
                    //"filter": filter // nach PLM steps
                        }
            },
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "Customer" }, // 1Customer
                    { "data": "Program_Name" }, //2Program
                    { "data": "Vehicle_Model"}, //3Vehicle Model
                    { "data": "CBU"}, //4CBU
                    { "data": "PLM_Step"},  // 5RFI/RFQ
         ],
    });
```

This will give me  one table with all the elements which I would like to see.

```
       Customer | Program Name | Vehicle Model | CBU     | PLM Step
       ___________________________________________________________
   1.   Audi   |  abc           | A2            | CBUAudi| 1
   2.  BMW      | 123            | X5           | CBUBMW  | 1
```

But I would like to have it like

```
Customer          Audi       Program Name     abc
Vehicle Model     A2         CBU              CBU Audi
PLM Step           1
```

.... and again this kind of table for each record in the dataset.

How is this possible with Javascript?

A link to where I could find help would also be nice.

Comment: not clear at all what your issue is

Comment: I would like to get a table each record.

Comment: will need to create your own ajax call and loop over data to create a table for each record then.

Comment: try this `append('<table id="Overview" border="1" class="compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr><th>Customer</th></tr><tr><th>Program Name</th></tr><tr><th>Vehicle Model</th></tr><tr><th>CBU</th></tr><tr><th>PLM Step</th></tr></tfoot></table>');`

Comment: Hello Arun, if I c&p your text then I just see the headlines under each other. but no records will be showed.

Comment: @charlietfl I get back all the records, but they will be shown just in that table like i have written. And If I change the format of the table like Arun has written, the I jsut see the header but no data. I thought like you have written to make a loop around th ecreation of the Table or to make a loop inside the table for each record. But how to make a loop there`?

Comment: I have there the "columns": but how to write that I want to have rows?

Comment: you need to parse each object in array (within loop of array) to a row for each table you create. This will all be done in the success callback of your ajax

Comment: So, how to do that. Could you give me a code example?